# Insert and Read row in one database call, Postgresql and C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

Sorry if this is a silly question, how can we insert a row in postgresql database and read the same row again in one call?

`ExecuteReader` doesn't insert rows in database, `ExecuteScalar` and `ExecuteNonQuery` will return only one allow.

Is there a command to read entire row after inserting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query has to have the two commands, end each command with a semi-colon

```
String query = @"INSERT INTO table (a,b) VALUES (1,'x');
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (a = 1);";
```

Use `ExecuteReader(query)` It will work fine.

Who said `ExecuteReader` can't be used for inserts ?

All 3 `Execute-` methods can execute whatever commands to the database however, `ExecuteReader` will read the returned rows, `ExecuteNonQuery` will not return any result, `ExecuteScalar` only returns the value from the first column of the first row of your query.

Comment: Hi Siraj,

Thanks for the answer I am passing Stored Proc in Execute Reader and its not inserting anything..

Comment: It was mistake from my side, Apologies :(